# Can't find mysterious call to overloaded operator()

Tags: function, call, overloading, operator-keyword

How can I find an (apparently compiler-generated implicit) call to an overloaded operator() function?

The output from g++ is just

```
/tmp/<garbagename.o>:(.rodata._ZTVN3MAT3A1DIiEE[_ZTVN3MAT3A1DIiEE]+0x50): 
undefined reference to `A1D<int>::operator()(A1D<int>)'
```

No "in function" or any other indication of where the function is being called. JUST THAT ONE LINE OF OUTPUT - NOTHING MORE besides error: ld returned 1 exit status.

The code that causes the undefined reference I have reduced to just the non-functioning skeleton:

```
A1D<int> find(A1D<bool> data) {
   A1D<int> nothing;
   return nothing;
}
```

There is a copy constructor for A1D but it DOES NOT invoke operator(). 
Bottom line:

1) The function is declared (in the template class declaration for A1D):
virtual inline A1D operator()(A1D A);

2) I have purposely not defined A1D::operator()(A1D), because I suspected that my implementation for it was being called when I did not expect it to be. So... I understand why it is undefined. I don't understand why it is referenced because I don't see any references.

3) Again, I do not expect the function to be called because it does not appear to be referenced anywhere in my code.

3) I reduced my main program to an empty main(){} with just an include of the template header file containing the definition for A1D and a second header file containing the definition of find().

4) If I remove the definition for the find function, then the error goes away and the executable (which does nothing) links without error.

5) I am aware that the copy constructor for A1D is invoked for the find() function as part of the return linkage, but I don't see any connection between that and the
    operator()(A1D)
function.

I would like to get the g++ compiler to tell why it is generating a call to operator()(A1D). I tried "-v" but that was not helpful. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By experimenting I found that the "virtual" declaration partially explains the issue. Even though the function is inline and it is never invoked by my code either explicitly or implicitly, it appears that g++ wants it defined. If it is not declared virtual, then the compiler/linker don't need a definition.

I was going down this road (deliberately not defining a function) to try to track down why/where the function was being called. Apparently, g++ is not going to cooperate. I will have to debug in some different way.

I still have two complaints about g++ related to this posting:

1) It doesn't seem that an inline function that is never invoked should have to be defined, even it is declared virtual.

2) There is a need to be able to ask g++ to tell the programmer WHY it is referencing a given entry point in the object file that it generates. Explicit reference? C++ language implicit call?  Something else?  And where in the user's code was the corresponding rule invoked?....